# Intellij is ignoring Maven settings

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Intellij 2020.2.3 with Maven 3.6

I have a Test-class which is dependant on a junit-library.
No matter what I try, when trying to resolve the library, maven is ignoring the settings.xml and the localRepository-location.

The junit-folder within C:\Users[username]\.m2\repository gets updated, even though I have defined a custom location within the Settings of Intellij as well as in the settings.xml.

The credentials I've set to access the local artifactory seem to be ignored, as Intellij is logging a 401.

I've also copied the settings.xml into C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/conf and C:\Users[username]\.m2 but to no avail.

I also find it strange that the junit-library is ignored even if copied manually into the local-repository folder underneath C:\Users[username]\.m2\repository. So I cannot even manually provide the dependency.

Is there some magical place from where it grabs the settings which I am not aware of?

**Edit**

My phrasing was unlucky. I tried to run a single test via run-configuration. Therefore the library in question was "junit-platform-launcher".

Solved by adding it as an explicit test-dependecy according https://stackoverflow.com/a/67104089/2746919

**Edit 2**

As I found out, these dependencies are resolved using the repositories defined under Settings -> Remote Jar Repositories. After adding username/password to the URL I could remove the explicit dependencies mentioned in edit 1 as it solved the previously mentioned 401.

These settings can also be seen in the jarRepositories.xml found in the .idea folder.

Comment: What does the output of `mvn -X clean test` give you when it comes to trying to resolve the dependency?  Note that debug output is really really verbose and you don't want to put all of it in your question.

Comment: The code 401 means authorization failure which means the credentials are taken into account but obviously wrong...

Comment: @Makoto and khmarbaise: The problem is, as long as I don't explicitly include the junit-platform-launcher, the maven configuration is ignored when using a run configuration for a single unit-test (which then attempts to resolve junit-platform-launcher implicitly.) Using the command line works.