# Using @DataJpaTest in Spring Boot 3.0.0 Integration test causes Test discovery error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, junit-jupiter

Whenever I add @DataJpaTest to a test test execution fails with the following error:

```java
import com.owino.paginateddata.entities.Tweet;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class PersistTweetTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void shouldPersistTweetTest(){
        var entity = entityManager.persistAndFlush(new Tweet(1L,"#goodvibes #sweetypie", "2022-12-11","11:00PM"));

        Assertions.assertThat(entity).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(entity.getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
        Assertions.assertThat(entity.getContents()).isEqualTo("#goodvibes #sweetypie");
        Assertions.assertThat(entity.getDateString()).isEqualTo("2022-12-11");
        Assertions.assertThat(entity.getTimeString()).isEqualTo("11:00PM");
    }
}
```

```java
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'com.owino.paginateddata.persistence_test.PersistTweetTest'] resolution failed
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:46)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
    ... 13 more
```

Tests that are not annoted with @DataJpaTest and @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) execute smoothly. I have observed this only in Spring Boot 3.0.0, I am running these tests smoothly on 2.7.x.

While Running $ mvn test I noticed maven skips the test.

Running on Intelij 2022.3 leads to the above error being produced.

Comment: Take a look at the solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315013/failed-to-resolve-junit-platform-launcher-1-6-3-intellij